# Escaping quotes in PHP from MySQL result (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, stripslashes, addslashes

The string to display comes from a MySQL table. I use PDO queries. The string contains double quotes:

> Older spelling (from French). The modernized "petty larceny" is now preferred.

This is a definition of a dictionary entry that is displayed if available:

```
$search_results .= (!empty($english_definition)? "<a class=\"definition\" href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"popover\" rel=\"popover\"
data-content=\"".$english_definition."\">".$english."*</a>" : $english);
```

Because of the quotes, the definition is cut to after the word "modernized".

I tried using `addslashes()` but the result is that a single slash is displayed, and nothing after it.

I also tried adding slashes inside the table field, e.g.

> Older spelling (from French). The modernized \"petty larceny\" is now preferred.

Without `stripslashes()` in the PHP code, only the first backward slash is displayed and nothing after it.

When I add `stripslashes()`, nothing is displayed after the word "modernized".

So, this is where I am stuck.

**ADDITIONAL CODE:**
This is how I insert new terms and definitions. I have added `htmlspecialchars()` for input where quotes could exist:

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $english                = htmlspecialchars($_POST['english']);
        $english_abbr           = $_POST['english_abbr'];
        $variant                = $_POST['variant'];
        $bulgarian              = htmlspecialchars($_POST['bulgarian']);
        $bulgarian_abbr         = $_POST['bulgarian_abbr'];
        $theme_id               = $_POST['theme_id'];
        $english_definition     = htmlspecialchars($_POST['english_definition']);
        $bulgarian_definition   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['bulgarian_definition']);

        // Check if an entry already exists
        $exists = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".DICTIONARY_TABLE." WHERE english = :english AND theme_id = :theme_id ");
        $exists->execute(array(':english' => $english, ':theme_id' => $theme_id));
        $count = $exists->rowCount();
        if($count > 0) {
            echo "<h3 style=\"color:navy; background:transparent;\">&#8658; An entry in the same theme already exists.</h3>";
        }
        else {
            $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ".DICTIONARY_TABLE." 
                                    (english, english_abbr, variant, bulgarian, bulgarian_abbr, theme_id)
                                    VALUES
                                    (:english, :english_abbr, :variant, :bulgarian, :bulgarian_abbr, :theme_id)");
            $insert->execute(array(':english'           => $english, 
                                    ':english_abbr'     => $english_abbr,
                                    ':variant'          => $variant,
                                    ':bulgarian'        => $bulgarian,
                                    ':bulgarian_abbr'   => $bulgarian_abbr,
                                    ':theme_id'         => $theme_id));

            if($insert) {
                echo "<h4 style=\"color:green; background:transparent;\">&#8658; Term \"$english\" inserted successfully.</h4>";

                if(!empty($english_definition) || !empty($bulgarian_definition)) {      
                    $insert_id = $db->lastInsertId();
                    $insert_def = $db->prepare(
                            "INSERT INTO ".DICTIONARY_DEFINITIONS." 
                            (term_id, english_definition, bulgarian_definition)
                            VALUES
                            (:term_id, :english_definition, :bulgarian_definition)");
                    $insert_def->execute(array(
                            ':term_id' => $insert_id, 
                            ':english_definition'   => $english_definition,
                            ':bulgarian_definition' => $bulgarian_definition));

                    if($insert_def) {
                        echo "<h4 style=\"color:green; background:transparent;\">&#8658; Definition(s) inserted successfully.</h4>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<h4 style=\"color:red; background:transparent;\">&#8658; There was a problem inserting the definition(s)!</h4>";
                    }
                }

                unset($_POST); $_POST = array();
            }
            else { 
                echo "<h4 style=\"color:red; background:transparent;\">&#8658; There was a problem executing the query: </h4>";
            }
        }
        include("insert_form.php");
    }
    else {
        include("insert_form.php");
    }
```

Comment: Are you using prepared statements with placeholder values? There's your answer.

Comment: Yes, I am. But before I changed `$english_definition = $_POST['english_definition'];` to `$english_definition = htmlspecialchars($_POST['english_definition']);` I had the problem as described.

Comment: You're using the wrong method here, that's only relevant for displaying on a page. You should be using  [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). They are intended to safely insert your data without mangling it. You're doing some double escaping there that's causing problems. What version of PHP are you using? Try and check what values you're binding to your statement to see where the double escaping is coming from. Maybe there's other code that touches these, possibly even JavaScript.

Comment: @tadman, Could you please have a look at the full insert query I added to my question, and let me know if this really is the wrong method? I have followed sources on PHP.net and here - of course, not being an expert, I might be doing things not as they should be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `htmlspecialchars()` function when you save it to the database, and `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function when you want to echo it again.

[Link to htmlspecialchars() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

[Link to htmlspecialchars_decode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: What changes do I need to make to this particular string, which has already been written to the database, in order to test this? Should I add slashes, or not? I do the editing directly from PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried that (`htmlspecialchars()`). The quotes were converted into `&quot;`. Then echoed the result using `htmlspecialchars_decode()` -- but still get the same result -- the string is cut to after "modernized".

Comment: However... when I echo the result WITHOUT adding `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, the full string is displayed correctly!
So, the solution is then to use `htmlspecialchars()` when writing to the database, but just echo it without decoding.
Thanks!

Comment: You should be saving to the database in the neutral format and escaping with `htmlspecialchars()` only when you're displaying it. Using the HTML escaping in your database is asking for huge trouble because you'll have to display these raw or risk double escaping, exposing yourself to XSS problems.

Comment: @tadman, could you please elaborate as I'm not sure I understand what "in the neutral format" means?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a vague question and if you would use pdo right i don't even think you should have to deal with the slashes but if you wan't the data to be displayed without slashed have you tried using string replace?

```
$search_result = str_replace ("/", "", $search_result);
```

This should achieve what you want if i understand you're question correctly

Comment: Sorry if my question is not very clear. I am new to PDO, so there is a chance I'm not doing things right, but then again, it's a simple insert and then fetch query... Here's the INSERT part:

`$insert_def = $db->prepare(
"INSERT INTO ".DICTIONARY_DEFINITIONS." 
(term_id, english_definition, bulgarian_definition)
VALUES
(:term_id, :english_definition, :bulgarian_definition)");

$insert_def->execute(array(
':term_id' => $insert_id, 
':english_definition' => $english_definition,
':bulgarian_definition' => $bulgarian_definition));`

I have now added `htmlspecialchars()` and it works!